# batch processing of images in python opencv is not working

Tags: python, opencv, image-loading

I used this code to read series of png format images in a folder. but it reads only one image successfully. What is the reason for that?

```
from glob import glob

for fn in glob('*.png'):
   im = cv2.imread(fn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only got one variable (called `im`) so it can only hold one image. You probably want a list of images:

```
# Make empty list
imgs = []

for fn in glob('*.png'):
    im = cv2.imread(fn, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    imgs.append(im)
```

Or, you can use a *"list comprehension"*:

```
imgs = [ cv2.imread(fn, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) for fn in glob('*.png') ]
```